# How do I prioritize WLAN over LAN in Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, priority

I have an issue with my Wireless disconnecting when I dock my notebook. I usually have a Citrix session going and if the connection is changed from WLAN to LAN, the session crashes/disconnects.

SO...i'd like my WLAN to remain on AND be prioritized over the LAN (I need to have the LAN due to company policy, for push updates etc.).

I have tried setting Automatic Metric for the LAN to 20 and the WLAN to 10, but still lose the Citrix session. Then noticed that the WLAN is automatically disconnected when LAN is detected, how do I prevent that?

Comment: Have you checked BIOS if the two can be connected at the same time?
Maybe pushed by GP?
Best,
A.

Comment: I can manually connect the WLAN after docking, so yes they can be enabled simultaneously.

Comment: I can manually connect the WLAN after docking, so yes they can be enabled simultaneously.

Comment: Just figured it out. There is a power management setting in BIOS for newer Dell notebooks that enables/disables control of wireless connections when system is connected to wired network. Disabling this control solved the issue. thanks anyways Akoska :D